# values from different tables and update through trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

I have 3 tables:

1. product (`pid  unit_price`) primary key pid
2. checkout (`pid order_num qty`) primary key pid + order num
3. order (`order_num total`) primary key order num

I want to create trigger when I add something in checkout, total price should be calculated using price and qty and updated in orders. Multiple products for same order in checkout.

Comment: Welcome to SO! what have you tried?

Comment: You can create an After Insert trigger.

Comment: And if you update or delete something?  Or if a concurrent transaction adds, updates, or deletes something, when one transaction cannot "see" what another is doing?  You'd be better off not using triggers and using a query or view (or, if necessary, a materialized view) to calculate totals on demand.